# Problem with while loop and if/else statement

Tags: java

I'm just having a bit of a problem with the output of this program (mostly the if/else statement). The problem is the if statement output duplicates itself and gives 2 separate answers while the else statement prints out like it's supposed to but wrong integer and result.

I'm trying to get the output something like this.

Example:

> The sum of the values above the threshold of 62 is *blahblahblah*
>
> The sum of the values below the threshold of 62 is *blahblahblah*

However, my program is printing out something like this (I'm trying to get it to print out the 50 in the integer variable slot for both outputs):

Example #'s: 30, 60, 50, 20, 10, 40

> The sum of the values above the threshold of 30 is 30
>
> The sum of the values above the threshold of 50 is 80
>
> The sum of the values below the threshold of 10 is 90

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ThresholdTotals {
 public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File ("values.text"));

  int num = 0;
  int max = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    num = sc.nextInt();
    max = sc.nextInt(); // used to print the 2nd highest max
    if (num >= max) {
      sum += num;
      System.out.println("The sum of the values above the threshold of " + num + " is " + sum); 
     // prints out a certain integer and the sum of the values greater than it
  } 
    else {
      sum += num;
      System.out.println("The sum of the values below the threshold of " + num + " is " + sum);
     // prints out a certain integer and the sum of the values less than it
      }
    }
sc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't read out what's your purpose. Please give us an example. What's the numbers in values.text, and what's your purpose output and what's really output.

Comment: You want to output something after you're done processing all the numbers in your input - but your code is outputting something as it reads each number in your input, instead.

Comment: @Bejond The purpose of this program is to print out the output like the example I posted in the first yellow box. I posted an example of the output I'm receiving right below it.

Comment: You have to add to int another "else if" and then input another int in the scanner.